# how to Read Binary Records in the SCOSTA smart card

Tags: smartcard, apdu, scosta

I have successfully created MF,DF,EF file format in Scosta card.
I Successfully write binary file with APDU Command 00 D0 00 04 06 Data field which is Six byte in len,Now I want to Read binary data From EF (E0 05).I tried out various Apdu command.But it is not working properly.Help me out,so i tried to read binary APDU Command 00 B0 00 00 00 00 FF But it is not working properly.so let me know what is the exactly pass the value with P1 and P2 to read binary data from EF(E0 05).

Thanks

Comment: What does not work?What happens instead?  Did you only create the file with 10 records or have the APPEND RECORD commands have been executed?  In any case your *Write Record* command seems not to have a valid LC. I strongly recommend putting the relevant information in the question right from the beginning to avoid downvotes and close requests.

Answer (score 0):

Due to substantial gaps in the question I give some hopefully useful information:

- Before reading the EF has to be selected
- P1 is the high byte (with exception of MSB) and P2 the low byte of the offset (starting with zero)
- Simply try "00 B0 00 00 00" first, this should give you all bytes, if the file is 6 bytes long (what you are trying is an extended length APDU with 255 bytes result, which reduces probability to be understood by reader and card)

Recommendation: Find a copy of ISO 7816-4 copy and read it before asking further questions of this level.